# Where to find info on how to set up a vm in redhat 7.2

Tags: virtual-machine, samba, virtualization

I have a RedHat 7.2 server that was set up by someone else long ago as an e-commerce server.  It is still in use for that purpose and I dare not make significant changes to it as my Linux-fu is weak.

But now I want to set up a virtual machine to run under redhat and can't find a source of information.  Searches on Google seem to give plenty of info about how to set up a VM under, say, Windows to run Linux in, but not how to set one up in Linux itself.

When I have the VM I shall be running Fedora in it and using its Samba to share directories with Windows 7.

The reason for all this is that the Samba version I'm using (vsn.2.2.3a) is incompatible with Win7 and  if I try to update to a version that does work with Win7 (3 or later), I hit a cascade of rpm dependencies that, after a lot of searching, I still don't know how to resolve.

Can anyone give me pointers on where to start please?

Thanks

Roy

Comment: Sorry RedHat 7.2 is more than 10 years old with Kernel 2.4. You should contact RedHat directly but i highly doubt you will get any support from them

Comment: You don't install anything on Red Hat 7.2. You install whatever you want on some other machine, and work out an upgrade path as quickly as possible. (Upgrade path = install a new distribution on new hardware, and do what it takes to update whatever software the site is running on.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry. This is not possible. Red Hat 7.2 is a 2001/2002-era operating system released far before [Linux kernel-based virtualization](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) was an option.

Your best option is to build a new system using a modern variant of Red Hat or CentOS, and migrate services. I'd urge you to contact an outside Linux resource (consultant, etc.) to help ease the migration. In general, this is not an unreasonable task.

Comment: If the server is an e-commerce server (oh, I hope it really isn't) then it has been running without updates for nearly a decade as well.  There are probably hundreds of exploitable packages on it.  If it is in any way public-facing, it's probably already compromised.

Comment: It is not public facing.  It reaches out to a PHP/MySQL based web site which is up to date to download data.